# jQuery each, find, and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dynamic

Currently I have a function that iterates through multiple divs, finds a div with the class name of ".courseArea", and return it to be appended by another

```
function getCourseAreaBySemester(sem_id) {
    $(".semesterPanel").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == sem_id) {
            return $(this).find('.courseArea'));
        }
    });
}
```

Second function to process the return

```
var targetSemester = getCourseAreaBySemester(semesterData[i]['semester_id']);
            console.log(targetSemester);
            targetSemester.append(createCourse(semesterData['courses'][j]));
```

The console prints out "undefined", and therefore, I cannot do a .append().

But if I console.log right before the return, it returns `[<ul class=​"courseArea">​</ul>​]`

I know it works If I don't use the .each() function. However, I need to select by ID.

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Or of an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to add your html

Comment: And what's the `function` keyword doing in that first code-block?

Comment: Neither of these 'functions' are actual `functions`. The first's syntax is way off and the second is just a bunch of calls to functions.

Comment: Sorry, bad pasting. Fixed.

Comment: its returning for the first function , not the second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getCourseAreaBySemester(sem_id) {
    var result;
    $(".semesterPanel").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == sem_id) {
            result = $(this).find('.courseArea'));
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Returning the value of the inner function inside it obviously does not affect the return value of the getCourseAreaBySemester function!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning anything from `getCourseAreaBySemester`. A `return` within `each` is closed and only returns within the `each` callback

You could simplify and just use the ID as selector since ID's in a page are unique:

```
function getCourseAreaBySemester(sem_id) {   
    return $('#'+sem_id).find('.courseArea');
}
```